# How to align a backup IP block to same Virtual IP definitions as active block?

Tags: firewall, fortigate

We recently added a backup ISP for our rack. Simply put, in the event that our primary connection goes down we would like to be able to switch to our backup connection. Right now we have primary external addresses pointing to internal addresses through VirtualIPs. Is there a way to have this abstracted so we can change the source IP block without having to change every VIP definition? Best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Did that answer you; https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Fortinet-Forum/SOLVED-VirtualIP-on-2-WAN/m-p/71109?m=171647

Comment: @yagmoth555 unfortunately not